# Lazy loading a RSS feed in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, lazy-loading

My Wordpress website is slowed down by a plugin i wrote myself. This plugin loads events from a RSS feed on a different site.

I have disabled the plugin and it made a difference of 20 in Google Page Speed.

How can i lazy load a RSS feed in Ajax or Javascript?

The code i have:

```
  $rss = simplexml_load_file(get_option('capu_url'));

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
     echo '<h4><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h4>";
 //echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";


$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->strictErrorChecking = FALSE ;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($item->description);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                     
$nodes = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="ee-event-datetimes-ul"]');   // get <ul>'s with class 'up'
foreach($nodes as $node) {                      // loops through each <ul>
    foreach($node->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {    // loops through the <li>'s

    echo $li->nodeValue . "<br/>\n";   // echo's the <li> elements
```

Comment: Could you maybe show us the code you already have?

Comment: Of course, i will add it right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the access you have to the server, consider running a cron job, for example once an hour to retrieve the RSS feed, convert it to JSON and save it as a file somewhere within the web root.

Now you can use JavaScript to retrieve the feed asynchronously from your server as a JSON data file and display it on your site.

If you don't have shell access, try to use the [`wp_cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) function in Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed a good solution in speeding up the widget